# GNUplot Mixed Graph with errorbar and linespoints

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graph, drawing, gnuplot

I have my data file as ;

```
#"U"
17.90 17.92 0.03
17.91 17.93 0.03

#"M"
11.22 16.71 0.02
11.44 16.64 0.02

#"T"
33.22 16.36 0.01
22.3 16.34 0.01
```

I want to draw 1:2 and 3rd is the error on y-axis. I want these as linespoints with errors so I use the code :

```
plot 'doc.dat' u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars ls 1 i 0 t "U", '' u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars ls 2 i 1 t "M", '' u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars ls 3 i 2 t "T"
```

but getting errors. I don't understand which part I am doing wrong.

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: ';' expected and undefined variable: i . Graph comes with the errorbars but they are all same colour and there is no lines at all. I need each set with different colour but i thought it was default too

Comment: The index specification comes immediately after the filename before the using specification.

Comment: I changed the order as you have mentioned but still the same problem continues same error and still same colours.. This is so confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in gnuplot `help index`: **Data sets are separated by pairs of blank records.**

So to use index, you need to change you datafile to: (notice the double blanks)

```
#"U"
17.90 17.92 0.03
17.91 17.93 0.03


#"M"
11.22 16.71 0.02
11.44 16.64 0.02


#"T"
33.22 16.36 0.01
22.3 16.34 0.01
```

Then concerning your plot line, as suggested by @Matthew, you need to change to:

```
plot 'doc.dat' i 0 u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars ls 1 t "U", '' i 1 u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars ls 2 t "M", '' i 2 u 1:2:3 w yerrorbars ls 3 t "T"
```

### Note:

Removing comments will help a lot the script:

```
"U"
17.90 17.92 0.03
17.91 17.93 0.03


"M"
11.22 16.71 0.02
11.44 16.64 0.02


"T"
33.22 16.36 0.01
22.3 16.34 0.01
```

you can simplify you script as:

```
set key autotitle columnhead
plot for [a=0:2] "doc.dat" i a w yerr
```

or even better by automatically calculating the number of blocks:

```
set key autotitle columnhead
stats "doc.dat"
plot for [a=0:STATS_blocks] "doc.dat" i a w yerr
```

Finally, if you want **both** errorbars and straight lines between points, the `plot` line  becomes:

```
plot for [a=0:STATS_blocks] "doc.dat" i a w l, for [a=0:STATS_blocks] "" i a w yerr pt 0
```

Have a look at `help stats` and `help for` in gnuplot

Comment: Thank you very much, that works quite well but still the lines are not connected when i add w linespots i again get the same error...

Comment: you need to plot it twice, something like this: `plot for [a=0:2] "test.txt" i a w yerr ls a+1, for [a=0:2] "" i a w l ls a+1 not`

Comment: Now I have a better view about the general stuff. Thank you very much.